# When does a proof have too little details? (prove that the reflexive closure of a strict partial order is a partial order)

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Suppose $R$ is a strict partial order on $A$. Let $S$ be the reflexive closure of $R$. Then $S$ is a partial order on $A$.
$Proof.$
$R$ is transitive and antisymmetric, and $i_A$ is reflexive. So since $S$ is just $R\cup i_A$, $S$ is a partial order on $A$. $\square$

Does this proof have too little details? Is it even valid? In general, when does a proof have too little details for it to be considered bad?